# Eigen-decomposition one eigenpair by one eigenpair?

Tags: eigenvalues, eigensystem, complexity

Is it possible to conduct an Eigen-decomposition of a matrix one eigenpair by one eigenpair?

And related to this question, what is the time complexity of truncated eigendecomposition?

---

I am trying (hard) to find a way to reduce the time complexity of my algorithm which involves the calculation of eigendecomposition of a positive definite matrix. The full eigendecomposition is $O(n^3)$ in general. However, I may not need full eigendecomposition. I only need to stop when the $\lambda_i$, i.e. the $i$-th largest eigenvalue (and its eigenvector), is less than $\epsilon>0$.

Is there a way to do that? We might assume we know the number of eigenvalues greater or equal to $\epsilon$, if necessary, e.g. something like truncated eigendecomposition.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you only need the largest eigenvalues, what you are doing sounds like a rank-revealing QR or SVD decomposition to me. Have you looked into that? These are widely implemented operations; you don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: The following should already be known, it would be nice if this could be indicated in the question: The power iteration or inverse power iteration (with modifications for complex eigenvalues) give one eigenvalue at a time. One would need to add some matrix reduction or deflation method to get to the next pair. // Subspace iterations extend this concept by iterating several vectors at the same time and forcing them to stay orthogonal or linearly independent in some other way.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni : That is true. It seems unlikely that one can get a result about the structure of all eigenvalues without using some $O(n^3)$ operations, even if aggressive matrix splitting is used to quickly reduce the dimension.

Comment: Is your matrix sparse/structured in some way? (ie fast matrix-vector products?) Is it symmetric?

Comment: @rchilton1980 Yes. It is symmetric. There is no sparsity/structure in some way. Suppose the matrix $X$ is $p\times p$. First, we know that the matrix is a low rank, and the rank $r$ is much less than $p$. Secondly, we know that the Frobenius norm of the matrix is small, i.e. $||X||_F\leq\delta$ .

Comment: That A is low rank is information that should be included in the question, the first step is to find its low rank approximation (I suggest via randomized sampling if you already know what the rank r is, or maybe a quit-early variant of RRQR if the rank is dependent on some other parameters somehow). Then the eigendecomposition is pretty easy to write down from the low rank representation.